# Use test to check for condition with find and execdir option

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, find

I think I can keep my question short. Why does the following command produce no output?

```
find /usr/share/themes -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir test -d {}/gnome-shell \;
```

I expected it to print all folders in */usr/share/themes* that contain a folder *gnome-shell*.
Several websites suggest that this usage of test as a command in `exec`/`execdir` is possible.

From `man find`:

```
-exec command ;
              Execute  command;  true  if 0 status is returned. [...]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `–exec` and `–execdir` evaluate to true if the named program returns a 0 value as its exit status.

This means that, if you were to say something like `–execdir test -d {}/gnome-shell \; –print` or `–exec … \; –something`, the thing after the `–exec` would be processed if and only if the `test` command returned true.  As an extreme example, you could even say

```
find starting_dir … –execdir test –d {}/gnome-shell \; –exec rm –rf {} \;
```

although that’s not necessarily the best way to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. `find /usr/share/themes -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir test -d {}/gnome-shell \; -print` does the job.

Answer (score 1):

`test` does not output anything, it just returns the exit status.

However, if you are only testing in depth 1, you can avoid `find` completely:

```
ls -d /usr/share/themes/*/gnome-shell
```

Comment: I know that it just returns an exit status, but I think `-exec` checks that exit status (see my addition of the find man page in the question). 
As far as I know `ls` should not be used when the output is used as input for another command since it might print additional information or format the output.

Comment: @slosd: So search in depth 2 for gnome-shell and use the "another command" in execdir.

Comment: Good idea. `find /usr/share/themes -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -name gnome-shell -execdir pwd \;` produces what I want.